# Custom wallpapers are not showing when selected

Tags: desktop-background

I've added three custom wallpapers to the `/usr/share/backgrounds/` folder using the following Terminal method -

```
sudo cp /home/master/Downloades/company-wallpaper-1.jpg /usr/share/backgrounds/
```

However, when I right click on the desktop, select `Change Desktop Background`, click the `+` button and select any of the three I added, the desktop does not change and the new image is not displayed with a preview, as the defaults are.

Further more, if I browse to `/usr/share/backgrounds/` and try to open them I see the following error

> Could not load image 'company-wallpaper-1.jpg'.
>   Failed to open input stream for file

Yet if I open the image through the `/home/master/Downloads/` folder it works just fine.

Can anybody please help me solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: This is just a guess, but you may need to change permissions and/or ownership.  Run and post `ls -l` from `/usr/share/backgrounds` (make sure to include at least 1 wallpaper that was already there to compare permissions and ownership to your company wallpaper)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the file permissions by using the following code -

```
chmod -R 777 /usr/share/backgrounds
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to in the end use `sudo chmod 644 /usr/share/backgrounds/`